# How to add missing folder in Github

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am new to Github and facing the below issue:

1. I created a project in my local directory (on a Windows box).
2. I have created a repository in Github and followed the basic instructions given in the page (to add the code to Github).
3. The entire project got uploaded to Github except one folder.

Could anybody let me know how i could add this folder to repository? Your help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `git add foldername` then commit and push

Answer (score 5):

If that folder is empty, you won't be able to add it directly.

- Add a file in it (`.keep`),
- `git add` that folder (it will work because of the folder *content*),
- `git commit`
- and `git push`.

If that doesn't work:

- `git clone` the github repo
- add your folder in it
- `git add yourfolder`
- `git commit` -m "yourfolder"
- `git push`

Check if you have a `.gitignore` file anywhere in your repo, to see if "`Yourfolder`" is declared as ignored.

You also can type:

```
git check-ignore -v yourfolder
```

That allows you to check if there is any gitignore rule which would cause yourfolder to be ignored.

Comment: the folder was not empty, it had some files in it. But i did not get the reason to why it was not uploaded. All the other files and folders were uploaded correctly!

Comment: @Varun do you have a .gitignore?

Comment: could you please let me know how exactly should i use that? i am pretty new to Github. It would also be helpful if you could let me know what exactly does the .gitignore command do

Comment: @VarunU I was talking about a file named `.gitignore`, not a command. i have edited my answer with more details.